# Push Notification Icon

Tags: android, parse-platform, notifications, icons, push

I'm trying to change the default notification icon and got the following result:

[image]

How can I remove the white circle in the right corner of the image?

```
public class ParseReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
protected Bitmap getLargeIcon(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    return icon;
   }
}
```

Another question:

[image]

How can I change the white image circle in the notification bar by a colored?

Comment: show your launcher icon

Comment: My icon is the one with the japan flag at the first image. I want it to be colored in the status bar as well.

Answer (score 2):

Both the circle in the bottom right, and the circle in the stats bar are controlled by the 'small icon', not the large icon.

You can set it by overriding getSmallIcon in your `ParseReceiver`, or a much simpler way is to add

`<meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/push_icon"/>`

to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.